# tell pure touch event and pure gesture event apart?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css

I am doing iphone web development and I've noticed that: gesture events can also be touch events, which means a touch event handler also fires up when there is a gesture event.

Any way that I can add specific event handler to gesture (not touch)? Or how can I know if this is a pure touch event or a pure gesture event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: This was an answer for your original revision that asked if something is a "pure touch event". It won't help you with your changed question on getting pure gesture events.

Listen for gesture events and have a `gesturing` boolean that you check during touch events that is set to `true` by the event handler for the gesture events and set back to `false` by the event handler for the touch events if it is `true`.

I have not researched at all about these events, but here's a sample implementation:

```js
var gesturing = false;
document.addEventListener(aTouchEventName, function () {
    if (gesturing) {
        return gesturing = false;
    }
    // your touch event handler code here
}, false);

document.addEventListener(aGestureEventName, function () {
    gesturing = true;
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the specifics on this but it looks like there are 3 events fired in a gesture.

-touchstart

-touchmove

-touchend

Ultimately your touch end will fire.  What you can do is create a threshold amount between your star and end.  And trigger a custom event if the (x,y) difference is past a certain amount.

Comment: How to avoid these 3 events when doing gesture?